# V-Sync and weird behavior (causing overheating)

Tags: nvidia, xorg, display, overheating

In some game (Eve Online), VSync is somewhat broken on Ubuntu. Well. Maybe it is coming from the game itself, but some things tell me I can configure Ubuntu to get it work.

#### How did I find out about that issue

My computer was overheating when running that game, but only when I select that Windows (I could run a `htop` above it, and my CPUs cool down immediatly)

#### Expected behavior

VSync works fine and caps my FPS to 120Hz, as my laptop's monitor is.

#### Faulty behaviors

Well, there are differents things to say that drive me mad.

1. **Laptop monitor alone**

I've narrowed the issue coming from the VSync because my FPS went all the way to the moon (400 to 800, and I don't have Linus T. computer) when I selected the Window, and where capped to 60 when I selected another Windows.

I tried to fix that by bypassing DE settings by editing `/etc/default/grub` and adding `nvidia-drm.modeset=1` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`. It went well tho, my FPS were capped. But my CPU didn't like it, and all X are pretty laggy.
(that modification allowed me to see "Synchronized = 1" on `nvidia-settings`).

I then reversed that and told myself I'll buy an external fan, don't do anything requiring me not to alt-tab to another windows time to time to cool down my CPU, as a workaround.

2. **I plug an external monitor**

Well, I wouldn't be here if I didn't observe a again weirder event about that. If I do have an external monitor plugged in (and turned on, obviously), and I launch Eve Online, wether the window is on my external monitor or my laptop monitor : everything works great !!!

I do not understand.

#### Workaround ? Resolution ?

Right now, I'm thinking more about a workaround from a resolution.

- either simulate the existence of that eternal monitor (althought nothing is plugged in), with "turn on" and "turn off" scripts.
- or resolve that issue, once for all

---

You'll find all, I hope, you need, here, about my computer (inxi, xrandr)

**No external monitor plugged in**

```
brieucdug@msi:~
 $ inxi -SPARM -GCDN -v1 -xGCRS
System:    Host: msi Kernel: 5.4.0-48-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 9.3.0 Desktop: KDE Plasma 5.18.5 
           Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: Micro-Star product: GF65 Thin 9SEXR v: REV:1.0 serial: <superuser/root required> 
           Mobo: Micro-Star model: MS-16W1 v: REV:1.0 serial: <superuser/root required> UEFI: American Megatrends 
           v: E16W1IMS.108 date: 12/04/2019 
CPU:       Topology: Quad Core model: Intel Core i5-9300H bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Kaby Lake rev: A L2 cache: 8192 KiB 
           flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 38400 
           Speed: 800 MHz min/max: 800/4100 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 800 2: 800 3: 800 4: 800 5: 800 6: 800 7: 800 8: 800 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel UHD Graphics 630 vendor: Micro-Star MSI driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 
           Device-2: NVIDIA TU106 [GeForce RTX 2060] vendor: Micro-Star MSI driver: nvidia v: 450.66 bus ID: 01:00.0 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.8 driver: modesetting,nvidia unloaded: fbdev,nouveau,vesa 
           resolution: 1920x1080~120Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: GeForce RTX 2060/PCIe/SSE2 v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 450.66 direct render: Yes 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel Cannon Lake PCH cAVS vendor: Micro-Star MSI driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 00:1f.3 
           Device-2: NVIDIA TU106 High Definition Audio vendor: Micro-Star MSI driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 01:00.1 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-48-generic 
Network:   Device-1: Intel Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak] driver: iwlwifi v: kernel port: 5000 bus ID: 00:14.3 
           Device-2: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet vendor: Micro-Star MSI driver: r8169 v: kernel 
           port: 3000 bus ID: 03:00.0 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 476.94 GiB used: 320.17 GiB (67.1%) 
           ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Samsung model: MZVLQ512HALU-00000 size: 476.94 GiB 
RAID:      Message: No RAID data was found. 
Partition: ID-1: / size: 467.96 GiB used: 320.17 GiB (68.4%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2 
Info:      Processes: 287 Uptime: 50m Memory: 7.62 GiB used: 3.14 GiB (41.1%) Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 9.3.0 
           Shell: bash v: 5.0.17 inxi: 3.0.38 


brieucdug@msi:~
 $ xrandr --prop
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
        CTM: 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
                0 1 
        CscMatrix: 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 
        BorderDimensions: 4 
                supported: 4
        Border: 0 0 0 0 
                range: (0, 65535)
        SignalFormat: TMDS 
                supported: TMDS
        ConnectorType: HDMI 
        ConnectorNumber: 2 
        _ConnectorLocation: 2 
        non-desktop: 0 
                supported: 0, 1
eDP-1-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
        EDID: 
                00ffffffffffff0006afedd000000000
                0b1d0104a52213780348358f57599229
                1e505400000001010101010101010101
                010101010101987180c870383e406c30
                aa0058c110000018782d80c870383e40
                6c30aa0058c110000018000000fd0030
                788a8a1e010a202020202020000000fe
                004231353648414e31332e30200a00f0
        PRIME Synchronization: 0 
                supported: 0, 1
        scaling mode: Full aspect 
                supported: Full, Center, Full aspect
        max bpc: 12 
                range: (6, 12)
        Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
                supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
        link-status: Good 
                supported: Good, Bad
        CONNECTOR_ID: 86 
                supported: 86
        non-desktop: 0 
                range: (0, 1)
   1920x1080    120.11*+  59.97    59.96    59.93    48.08  
   1680x1050     84.94    74.89    69.88    59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     85.00    74.76    70.00    59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     85.02    75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      85.00    60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864     100.00    85.06    85.00    75.00    75.00    70.00    60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      85.00    75.05    60.04    85.00    75.03    70.07    60.00  
   1024x768i     86.96  
   960x720       85.00    75.00    60.00  
   928x696       75.00    60.05  
   896x672       75.05    60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       85.00    75.00    70.00    65.00    60.00    85.14    72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       85.02    74.96    69.88    60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       85.08    74.76    70.06    59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       85.02    75.02    60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       85.09    60.00    85.01    72.81    75.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   720x400       85.04  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98    85.08  
   576x432      100.11    85.15    85.09    75.00    75.00    70.00    60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   640x350       85.08  
   512x384       85.00    75.03    70.07    60.00  
   512x384i      87.06  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   416x312       74.66  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       85.27    72.19    75.12    60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       85.18    72.81    75.00    60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   360x200       85.04  
   320x200       85.27  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
   320x175       85.27
```

**With my external monitor plugged** (laptop's is the primary)

```
brieucdug@msi:~
 $ inxi -SPARM -GCDN -v1 -xGCRS
System:    Host: msi Kernel: 5.4.0-48-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 9.3.0 Desktop: KDE Plasma 5.18.5 
           Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: Micro-Star product: GF65 Thin 9SEXR v: REV:1.0 serial: <superuser/root required> 
           Mobo: Micro-Star model: MS-16W1 v: REV:1.0 serial: <superuser/root required> UEFI: American Megatrends 
           v: E16W1IMS.108 date: 12/04/2019 
CPU:       Topology: Quad Core model: Intel Core i5-9300H bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Kaby Lake rev: A L2 cache: 8192 KiB 
           flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 38400 
           Speed: 800 MHz min/max: 800/4100 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 800 2: 800 3: 800 4: 800 5: 800 6: 800 7: 800 8: 800 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel UHD Graphics 630 vendor: Micro-Star MSI driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 
           Device-2: NVIDIA TU106 [GeForce RTX 2060] vendor: Micro-Star MSI driver: nvidia v: 450.66 bus ID: 01:00.0 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.8 driver: modesetting,nvidia unloaded: fbdev,nouveau,vesa 
           resolution: 1360x768~60Hz, 1920x1080~120Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: GeForce RTX 2060/PCIe/SSE2 v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 450.66 direct render: Yes 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel Cannon Lake PCH cAVS vendor: Micro-Star MSI driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 00:1f.3 
           Device-2: NVIDIA TU106 High Definition Audio vendor: Micro-Star MSI driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 01:00.1 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-48-generic 
Network:   Device-1: Intel Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak] driver: iwlwifi v: kernel port: 5000 bus ID: 00:14.3 
           Device-2: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet vendor: Micro-Star MSI driver: r8169 v: kernel 
           port: 3000 bus ID: 03:00.0 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 476.94 GiB used: 320.17 GiB (67.1%) 
           ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Samsung model: MZVLQ512HALU-00000 size: 476.94 GiB 
RAID:      Message: No RAID data was found. 
Partition: ID-1: / size: 467.96 GiB used: 320.17 GiB (68.4%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2 
Info:      Processes: 287 Uptime: 50m Memory: 7.62 GiB used: 3.14 GiB (41.2%) Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 9.3.0 
           Shell: bash v: 5.0.17 inxi: 3.0.38 


brieucdug@msi:~
 $ xrandr --prop              
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3280 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
HDMI-0 connected 1360x768+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 708mm x 398mm
        EDID: 
                00ffffffffffff00410c521e01010101
                1b110103804728788a288e9e55489724
                16484badce0031594559615981800101
                010101010101662150b051001b304070
                3600c48e21000018a91a00a050001630
                30203700c48e21000018000000fc0057
                584741205456202833290a20000000fd
                002f551f500e000a2020202020200136
                02032c71521f10202122140593041211
                0302011615070623090707830100006c
                030c002000b82dc03d013701011d00bc
                52d01e20b8285540c48e2100001a011d
                007251d01e206e285500c48e2100001e
                011d80d0721c1620102c2580c48e2100
                009e011d8018711c1620582c2500c48e
                2100009e0000000000000000000000f7
        CTM: 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
                0 1 
        CscMatrix: 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 
        BorderDimensions: 4 
                supported: 4
        Border: 0 0 0 0 
                range: (0, 65535)
        SignalFormat: TMDS 
                supported: TMDS
        ConnectorType: HDMI 
        ConnectorNumber: 2 
        _ConnectorLocation: 2 
        non-desktop: 0 
                supported: 0, 1
   1360x768      60.02*+
   1920x1080     59.94    50.00    29.97    25.00    23.98  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x768      59.99  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00    50.00  
   1024x768      85.00    75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       85.06    75.00    72.19    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       85.01    75.00    72.81    59.93    59.94  
eDP-1-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
        EDID: 
                00ffffffffffff0006afedd000000000
                0b1d0104a52213780348358f57599229
                1e505400000001010101010101010101
                010101010101987180c870383e406c30
                aa0058c110000018782d80c870383e40
                6c30aa0058c110000018000000fd0030
                788a8a1e010a202020202020000000fe
                004231353648414e31332e30200a00f0
        PRIME Synchronization: 0 
                supported: 0, 1
        scaling mode: Full aspect 
                supported: Full, Center, Full aspect
        max bpc: 12 
                range: (6, 12)
        Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
                supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
        link-status: Good 
                supported: Good, Bad
        CONNECTOR_ID: 86 
                supported: 86
        non-desktop: 0 
                range: (0, 1)
   1920x1080    120.11*+  59.97    59.96    59.93    48.08  
   1680x1050     84.94    74.89    69.88    59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     85.00    74.76    70.00    59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     85.02    75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      85.00    60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864     100.00    85.06    85.00    75.00    75.00    70.00    60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      85.00    75.05    60.04    85.00    75.03    70.07    60.00  
   1024x768i     86.96  
   960x720       85.00    75.00    60.00  
   928x696       75.00    60.05  
   896x672       75.05    60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       85.00    75.00    70.00    65.00    60.00    85.14    72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       85.02    74.96    69.88    60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       85.08    74.76    70.06    59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       85.02    75.02    60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       85.09    60.00    85.01    72.81    75.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   720x400       85.04  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98    85.08  
   576x432      100.11    85.15    85.09    75.00    75.00    70.00    60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   640x350       85.08  
   512x384       85.00    75.03    70.07    60.00  
   512x384i      87.06  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   416x312       74.66  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       85.27    72.19    75.12    60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       85.18    72.81    75.00    60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   360x200       85.04  
   320x200       85.27  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
   320x175       85.27  
  1280x1024 (0x1f7) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock  63.98KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock  60.02Hz
  1024x768 (0x215) 94.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1072 end 1168 total 1376 skew    0 clock  68.68KHz
        v: height  768 start  769 end  772 total  808           clock  85.00Hz
  1024x768 (0x216) 78.750MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1040 end 1136 total 1312 skew    0 clock  60.02KHz
        v: height  768 start  769 end  772 total  800           clock  75.03Hz
  1024x768 (0x217) 75.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1328 skew    0 clock  56.48KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  70.07Hz
  1024x768 (0x218) 65.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  60.00Hz
  800x600 (0x232) 50.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  856 end  976 total 1040 skew    0 clock  48.08KHz
        v: height  600 start  637 end  643 total  666           clock  72.19Hz
  800x600 (0x233) 49.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  816 end  896 total 1056 skew    0 clock  46.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  604 total  625           clock  75.00Hz
  800x600 (0x234) 40.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock  37.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock  60.32Hz
  640x480 (0x24c) 36.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  696 end  752 total  832 skew    0 clock  43.27KHz
        v: height  480 start  481 end  484 total  509           clock  85.01Hz
  640x480 (0x24e) 31.500MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  720 total  840 skew    0 clock  37.50KHz
        v: height  480 start  481 end  484 total  500           clock  75.00Hz
  640x480 (0x24f) 25.175MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
```

---

**Experiments :**

- Gnome/KDE : same results
- KDE compositor on/off : same results
- Eve's settings "interval one" is what I have when I'm at 60FPS with an external monitor. When I set "imediate rates", it goes all to the moon (and client crashs, eventually). Conclusion : "interval one" works (VSync is working to 60 FPS)

Comment: Maybe don't use v-sync at all "f your graphics processor is rendering more frames than the monitor can display, it may cause excess heat and screen tearing. " taken from https://www.maketecheasier.com/what-is-vsync/

Comment: @s1mme thanks for your interest. V-sync is to cap that amounts of frame per second. If I do not use it, it indeed render more fps. And that indeed increase overheating, that is exactly the issue I'm facing right now I'm looking to fix. That is said on the very last line of my question, in "experiments".